# Unable to use postgres with keycloak

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to use postgres with keycloak. following [Doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_database)

```
$ ls keycloak-9.0.0/modules/system/layers/keycloak/org/postgresql/main
  config.xml  postgresql-42.2.10.jar
```

This is the config.xml file.
**config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.10.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

These are the changes that i have made in standalone.xml
**standalone.xml**

```xml
<datasources>

    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
      <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</connection-url>
      <driver>postgresql</driver>
      <pool>
           <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
      </pool>
      <security>
           <user-name>postgres</user-name>
           <password>StrongPassword</password>
      </security>
   </datasource>

    <drivers>
         <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
              <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
          </driver>
     </drivers>


</datasources>

<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS">
```

The error i am getting.
*error*

```
06:13:39,430 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "postgresql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [org.postgresql] or one of it dependencies is missing: [org.postgresql]"
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can I suggest another way to configure this that is less likely to have an issue?  I use the following to configure PostgreSQL and Keycloak and it has been working well.  The key is to run this against a stopped Keycloak (using a fresh install).  Save the below to something like `setup-keycloak.cli`:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml --std-out=echo

batch
#
# remove the default provided datasource
#
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS/:remove

#
# add them
#
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=/path/to/postgresql-42.2.10.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)

/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS/:add(connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak_database,driver-name=postgres,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,initial-pool-size=4,max-pool-size=64,min-pool-size=4,password=keycloak_user,user-name=keycloak_pass)

run-batch
```

Then run this with `$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/jboss.sh --file=setup-keycloak.cli`.  This removes the KeycloakDS datasource, adds the PostgreSQL module, and recreates the KeycloakDS datasource with your parameters.  You can use this to reproduce the configuration any time as long as you have a local copy of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Comment: With keycloak 11.0.2 the command changed to `$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=setup-keycloak.cli`

Comment: When you say "recreate" or "reproduce" it means that the configuration you had previously in Keycloak (realms, clients, users) stay in the new configuration? Or will I lose all the data?

Comment: @DavidCG - that's a different thing.  If you recreate the database you will lose your data.  Take a look at the [Export and Import](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_export_import) admin guide to copy the data from your database.

Comment: Anyone trying this 2021 and beyond, just place the jar in the bin folder and write --resources=postgresql-42.2.10.jar. It automatically looks for the jar inside the bin folder.

Comment: @Grogu - how do you specify the credential information then?

Comment: @stdunbar: the way you do it in your script. Your script works but the jar has to be placed in the bin folder in my case for it to work. Otherwise, it cannot find the path.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you named the settings `config.xml` and should be `module.xml`.

Second you have to download postgresql jar to that location:
`curl -O https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-X.X.X.jar > /opt/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak/org/postgresql/main`
just replace the X.X.X with your version.

Then restart the server.

PS: you should use a vault for your password.

Comment: `PS: you should use a vault for your password.`

Why use vault if database is on localhost? If vault is external service that would introduce more possibilities for security breach

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but keep in mind that keycloak comes with bin/vault.sh and you can use it also locally. And at some point of time you will want to use your keycloak somewhere else and not only on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. create PostgreSQL **module.xml** (not config.xml) inside **base directory** (keycloak-11.0.2/modules/system/layers/base/com/postgresql/)
2. update standalone.xml

   ```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true"
               statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
       <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak</connection-url>
       <driver>postgresql</driver>
       <security>
           <user-name>db-user</user-name>
           <password>db-pass</password>
       </security>
   </datasource>
   <drivers>
   <driver name="postgresql" module="com.postgresql.h2">
       <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
       <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   </driver>
   <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
       <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
   </driver>
   </drivers>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in standalone:

1. In file module.xml

```
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">

  <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.23.jar" />
  </resources>

  <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

2.In file standalone.xml

```
    <datasources>
          
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"
                     pool-name="KeycloakDS"
                     enabled="true"
                     use-java-context="true"
                     statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}" >
        
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.XX:5432/Your-DataBase</connection-url>
             <driver>postgresql</driver>
        
             <pool>
                   <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
             </pool>
             <security>
                   <user-name>UserName</user-name>
                   <password>**********</password>
             </security>
        <statement>
                 <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                  <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
        </datasource>
        
        <drivers>
                 <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                  <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                 </driver>
        </drivers>
</datasources>
```

3.in file standalone.xml

```
    <default-bindings
        context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default"
        datasource="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"
        managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default"
        managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default"
        managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here from tutorials with Dockerized `jboss/keycloak` instance, you have built-in `rdbms` support without any configuration: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=kuser -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=kpass -e DB_VENDOR=postgres -e DB_ADDR=host:port -e DB_DATABASE=postgres -e DB_USER=pguser -e DB_PASSWORD=pgpass jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
```