# Unable to see Keycloak Tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

Although I tell Keycloak to use Postgres and the initial log indicates that it is using Postgres, Postgres database is not receiving a keycloak schema or any data.

keycloak/Dockerfile

```sh
FROM jboss/keycloak:14.0.0

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=3s --start-period=10s --retries=3 CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master

EXPOSE ${KEYCLOAK_PORT}

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose

```sh
keycloak_db:
  image: postgres:13
  volumes:
    - keycloak_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  restart: always
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE}
    POSTGRES_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
  ports:
    - ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PORT}:5432

keycloak:
  build:
    context: keycloak
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  restart: always
  environment:
    KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO
    ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
    DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
    DB_SCHEMA: 'public'
    DB_ADDR: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}
    DB_PORT: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PORT}
    DB_DATABASE: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE}
    DB_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
    KEYCLOAK_HOST: ${VITE_KEYCLOAK_HOST}
    KEYCLOAK_PORT: ${VITE_KEYCLOAK_PORT}
    KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
    KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
    KEYCLOAK_REALM: ${KEYCLOAK_REALM}
    KEYCLOAK_CLIENT: ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT}
  ports:
    - ${VITE_KEYCLOAK_PORT}:8080
  depends_on:
    keycloak_db:
      condition: service_started
  command: -b 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```sh
keycloak:
  build:
    args:
      INSTALL_DEV: "true"
  volumes:
    - ${pwd}/logs:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log
  environment:
    KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
    JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=false"
```

keycloak log

```sh
keycloak_1  | Added 'admin' to '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
keycloak_1  | -b 0.0.0.0
keycloak_1  | =========================================================================
keycloak_1  | 
keycloak_1  |   Using PostgreSQL database
keycloak_1  | 
keycloak_1  | =========================================================================
```

Later in the log it show H2 database is being used/mentioned.

```sh
keycloak_1  | [0m[0m18:14:36,051 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Database info: {databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/keycloak, databaseUser=SA, databaseProduct=H2 1.4.197 (2018-03-18), databaseDriver=H2 JDBC Driver 1.4.197 (2018-03-18)}
```

I noticed this [jboss - Unable to use postgres with keycloak - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337636/unable-to-use-postgres-with-keycloak)

Is more required to connect to Postgres beyond specifying DB with Environment variables? For example, [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_database) mention hacking internal xml configs.

Comment: "*not receiving a keycloak schema*" - maybe don't use `DB_SCHEMA: 'public'`?

Comment: What's up with `${KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}` and `${KEYCLOAK_DB_PORT}`? I didn't think these would be variable in a docker-compose network.

Comment: @Bergi `DB_SCHEMA: 'public'` was added but behaves the same without it. I have removed it because actually docs state that for `postgres` it is the default setting.

Comment: @Bergi `${KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}` is set to `keycloak_db` docker-compose postgres service container. I harded-coded to that same name with same results.

Comment: How are you connecting to PostgreSQL and how did you verify "database is not receiving a keycloak schema or any data"?

Comment: @JanGaraj I shell into db container: `docker exec -it keycloak_db psql -U postgres`. Returns: `psql (13.3 ...)`. I run: `\c keycloak`. It returns: `You are now connected to database "keycloak" as user "postgres"`. I run `\dt`. It returns: `Did not find any relations.`.

Comment: Perhaps relevant are log messages immediately following: `Using PostgresSQL database`. `Cannot start embedded server: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE": java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log/server.log (Permission denied)` and further down: `Failed to read or configure the org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager`. PERHAPS this forces Keycloak to abandon use of Postgres?

Comment: Clean and configure proper permissions for `${pwd}/logs/`. Try to clean/recreate `keycloak_db_data` volume, so Keycloak will try to create new DB from the scratch.

Comment: Ok resolved!!!!!!!!! I WAS using `FROM jboss/keycloak:14.0.0`. I changed to `FROM jboss/keycloak:latest` and it now WORKS!!!

Looks like they pushed an update to 14.0.0 YESTERDAY!! 14.0.0 *should* work now as well.

Comment: A factor that to also keep in mind is that using `volumes / ${pwd}/logs:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/log` IS a problem ... at least for me on Windows. Creating a dedicated volume for logs resolved this.