# Cannot see keycloak tables in external postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, keycloak

I am setuping Keycloak in a kubernetes minikube cluster.

I thought the setup worked as I could use keycloak but when I connect to the postgresql database I couldn't see any tables.
I have been reading similar issues like this one [Unable to see Keycloak Tables in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475007/unable-to-see-keycloak-tables-in-postgres). In my case it seems Keycloak only connects to H2 and not to postgresql.
Inside the logs I cannot see it making any attempts to connect to the DB specified in the yaml file.

These are an extract of the logs showing it connecting to H2:

```
default keycloak-7bdc548789-tknc2 keycloak 2023-04-10 02:14:15,634 TRACE [liquibase.database.core.H2Database] (main) Connected to SA@jdbc:h2:file:/opt/keycloak/bin/../data/h2/keycloakdb
default keycloak-7bdc548789-tknc2 keycloak 2023-04-10 02:14:15,634 TRACE [liquibase.database.core.H2Database] (main) Setting auto commit to false from true
default keycloak-7bdc548789-tknc2 keycloak 2023-04-10 02:14:15,634 DEBUG [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.liquibase.QuarkusLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (main) Using changelog file META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml and changelogTableName DATABASECHANGELOG
default keycloak-7bdc548789-tknc2 keycloak 2023-04-10 02:14:15,635 DEBUG [liquibase.database.core.H2Database] (main) Set default schema name to PUBLIC
```

These are Kubernetes yaml configuration files:
Yaml for Keycloak :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
          args: ["start-dev --log-level=TRACE"]
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              value: "POSTGRES"
            - name: DB_ADDR
              value: "keycloak-db"
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: "keycloak"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
              value: "http://devtest-ingress.info/api/keycloak/"
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: user
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
```

Yaml for Postgresql :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak-db
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak-db
          image: postgres:13
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: user
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: keycloak
          ports:
            - name: keycloak-db
              containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-db
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak-db
  ports:
    - name: keycloak-db
      port: 5432
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: I was thinking it is because of start-dev but if I use args: ["start", "--log-level=TRACE", "--hostname-strict=false"] instead it still connects to H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the yaml below is a bit different compared to the above.
The main reason why it was not working is that the environment variables have been changed in recent versions of keycloak and here is a working yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
          args: ["start", "--log-level=TRACE", "--hostname-strict=false"]
          env:
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: admin
            - name: KC_DB
              value: postgres
            - name: KC_DB_URL_HOST
              value: keycloak-db
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: edge
            - name: KC_DB_URL_DATABASE
              value: keycloak
            - name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
              value: http://nekonex-ingress.info/api/keycloak/
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: user
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-creds
                  key: password
            - name: KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME_STRICT
              value: "false"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080
```

Comment: The key is the `KC_` prefixes in the database configuration